# How to show pdf in browser instead of downloading IE

Tags: php, html, pdf

Okay, this works in Chrome for me, but not in IE; when I click the link to where the pdf is stored, I want it to open in a new page, and show the pdf in browser.

PHP:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   echo  "<a href='docs/1231231/1/" . $row['doc1'] . "'>file1</a><br/>";
   echo  $row['doc2'] . "<br/>";
   echo  $row['doc3'] . "<br/>";            
}
```

Why doesn't this work in IE?

Comment: Check to make sure the server is sending the correct mime type

Comment: sorry how do i do this?

Comment: Check the HTTP header that is being returned (there are [online tools](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php) that can do this). The `content-type` should be `application/pdf`.

Comment: thing is, what if the $row['doc2'] is a word document? the document types can be uploaded as .jpg .png .doc .pdf

Comment: Most (all?) web servers match MIME types by file extension. So as long as the file has the proper extension it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: if thats the case then why isnt IE showing the pdf on the browser instead of trying to make you download it?

Comment: Probably because the server isn't sending the correct MIME type. I would check that first, and if it isn't you'll need to configure it to send the right type for PDF files (`application/pdf`). This procedure will vary based on your web server.

Comment: Did you test that you can actually display PDF files in your IE? The PDF Plugin could be disabled. IE10 64bit broke a lot of 32bit plugins including pdf viewers. There could be many reasons why your setup disables PDF support in IE, so that would be the first thing I'd test.